# UIView + Cocos2D Element

Tags: uiview, cocos2d-iphone, uikit

I want to add a CCSprite on my UIView, is it possible to do that? What I found were the ways to add UIKit on Cocos2D, but I want the its reverse. I want to add Cocos2D on UIKit.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by setting following method in your uiviewcontroller class

```
- (void)setupCocos2D {
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200)
                               pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGB565   // kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                               depthFormat:0                        // GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16_OES
                    ];
glView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
[self.view insertSubview:glView atIndex:0];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] setView:glView];
CCScene *scene = [StarVideoView scene];
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:scene];
```

}

and calling this method in your viewDidLoad method as
    [self setupCocos2D];

here startVideoView is my ccscene class  and ofcourse you have to add cocos2d.h library in your uiviewcontroller class :)

Comment: Hi, this code is showing white screen only. But when I see at view debug navigator, it shows CCDirectorDisplayLink. This is by far, the closest way to add CCScene into my UIView. Any Ideas? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cocos2D does its drawings inside of a `EAGLView` class, which is just a wrapper for a `CAEAGLLayer`. So, you might try creating a director with its associated `EAGLView`, thendo this to add the cocos2d open gl layer to your view:

```
[myView.layer addSublayer:[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView].layer];
```